# Alternative python documentation

Tags: python

I've been checking out docs.python when I need something, is that the right site to be using? I come from java, and docs.python looks more like a tutorial site than a documentation site.

For example, when I lookup a class in the java api reference, **at a glance** I know all of its return types, method names and params, very simple, very effective website. With docs.python I have to read ALL of the method descriptions if I want to find a method that returns X...they dont have a short list of all the methods with no descriptions, and the method descriptions dont even tell you what exceptions are raised... there has to be a better site.

I've been playing around with python, I like the way it has less bloat, more tricks, but not being able to quickly look things up is killing me, **reading full pages of mostly useless information is interupting my train of thought.**

EDIT
Downvoters, I'm really trying to use this language here so... if you think I'm doingitwrong and have any suggestions... maybe explain how you roll because I've googled, binged, yandex'd duckduckgo'd and found no good suggestions, you cant be using docs.python... sure I could use a combo of dir() help() and doc.python, but thats beyond a joke.

EDIT
Ok, much to learn I still have, maybe when I learn python a little better I'll understand why the docs are the way they are, I suppose I should be happy there even is documentation :P

Thanks for the input folks

Comment: If you find it, make sure everyone knows about it ;-) I think php.net model (comments/wiki) is probably best; though in large sceheme of things, Python stdlib just makes sense -- you rarely need to reread the docs. Learn once and you're done ;-)

Comment: Obviously a matter of taste, however I find using `dir()` fast and easy. Particular if you use a decent shell like ipython. For quick checks I usually have ipython's qtconsole open. Wouldn't think that looking up docs online would be faster no matter how the docs would be organised. Matter of taste though I guess.

Comment: How do you guys find what exceptions might be raised, scrape the code for raise statements?

Comment: @MarkF207: that is a good question, and you should definitely ask it separately: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: hmm done Jacob: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24617977/how-to-find-what-exceptions-might-be-raised

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use introspection. Here are the most important ones (for me anyway):

- `dir(object)` returns all methods and attributes of an object.
- `module.__doc__` should return the module's doc string
- `type(object)` returns the object type
- `help(object)` might be useful too

Comment: Is there a way to find the return type, or would that be non pythonic :P

Comment: You can run `type(object())`. `object()` returns whatever and gives that as an input to `type` which tells you what it is

Comment: Yeah type() would quickly do the job for methods with no params, my real beef is with the verbosity of the official documentation...

Comment: @MarkF207 There is only one return type in Python, the PyObject. That's by design.

Comment: module.__doc__ is pretty nice, didnt knew about that one ^^

Answer (score 4):

[docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/) is the definitive reference for the Python language and library.

However, if you just want a list of methods in a module or class, you can use the built-in [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) and [`help()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#help) functions:

```
>>> import string

>>> dir(string)
['Formatter', 'Template', '_TemplateMetaclass', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__',
'__name__', '__package__', '_float', '_idmap', '_idmapL', '_int', '_long',
'_multimap', '_re', 'ascii_letters', 'ascii_lowercase', 'ascii_uppercase', 'atof',
'atof_error', 'atoi', 'atoi_error', 'atol', 'atol_error', 'capitalize', 'capwords',
'center', 'count', 'digits', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'hexdigits', 'index',
'index_error', 'join', 'joinfields', 'letters', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lowercase',
'lstrip', 'maketrans', 'octdigits', 'printable', 'punctuation', 'replace', 'rfind',
'rindex', 'rjust', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitfields', 'strip', 'swapcase',
'translate', 'upper', 'uppercase', 'whitespace', 'zfill']

>>> help(string.upper)
Help on function upper in module string:

upper(s)
    upper(s) -> string

    Return a copy of the string s converted to uppercase.
```

Comment: Tbh its more to quickly find out return types and exceptions, so I know how to properly handle the code

Answer (score 1):

When using [IPython](http://ipython.org/) for development, introspection gets even more easy thanks to tab-completion and the handy `foo?` shorthand for calling `help(foo)` to display a function/method/object/... docstring on the fly. A typical session might look a bit like:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: pd.Da<Tab>
pd.DataFrame     pd.DateOffset    pd.DateRange     pd.DatetimeIndex
In [3]: pd.DataFrame?
Type:       type
String Form:<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
File:       c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py
Docstring:
Two-dimensional size-mutable, potentially heterogeneous tabular data
[...]
```